# MS Word macro to search for and combined specific files into one document

Tags: vba, file, search, ms-word

I have encountered a stumbling block that exceeds my experience in working with MS Word macros.  Until recently, I have not had much need to use macros in Word or Excel, and what little bit I have needed was completely internal to the document or spreadsheet.

Now I find myself needing guidance on creating a macro that will draw on external files to create a temporary new file.

Within a working folder, I have a Master Document and numerous daughter documents.  The daughter documents all have file tags/keywords.

What I need is protected document (it can be DOC, PDF or HTML) that when opened will run a macro that will (1) query the user for a search term, (2) search all the files in the folder for file tags or keywords that match (3) open all those matching files into a single html page for display.

All the source files are Word 2010 but can be saved as PDF or HTML if it makes things easier.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Word's Master Document 'feature' is a disaster waiting to happen! Use it only if you don't value your work. See:

https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/WhyMasterDocsCorrupt.htm
http://www.addbalance.com/word/masterdocuments.htm

As for opening all your source documents in a single window, that's not possible unless you actually merge those documents into a single file. The code for that is complex. For some code to get you started, see:

https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/general-excel-discussion-other-questions/1037570-vba-combine-differently-formatted-word-files-into-1-while-preserving-layouts-post4980503.html#post4980503